# mediaplayer can play strings?

Tags: android

I have this idea and need to disscus it with you :

I have item A & B display text from database in a listview 
when user click the item A media player will play sound A
and when click the item B media player will play sound B

and this is normal play code :

```
    splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, R.raw.soundA);
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
```

so for the idea can I save "R.raw.soundA" in a column in the database and then use this code :

```
    splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, sound.getSOUND());
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
```

I dont need it in this time but I was thinking if this could work, so want to hear you 
.THANKS

Answer (score 0):

as long as the string is a `uri` that points to some place that holds some audio yes

Comment: The sound is at raw folder so the string shuld be R.raw.soundA ?

Comment: no `R.raw.soundA` gives you an `id` of the resource so putting that as a string will not work because that is not giving you a resource id, it is just a string. What you possibly do is store the resource id in the database but I am not sure how will that will work